# OVI/DUI Rights and Requirements

Tags: police, driving, ohio

I have been trying to find a definitive answer about what you are legally required to provide an officer at an OVI/DUI checkpoint in Ohio.

I know that Ohio is a "Stop and Identify" state. However, that only applies if you are reasonably suspected of committing a crime. Also, that is just name, address, and date of birth.

So are you required to identify yourself at an OVI/DUI Check Point?

Are you required to provide registration, proof of insurance and a drivers license?

I know you can invoke the right of silence and refuse consent to search but what do you actually have to answer?

Please only respond if you can provide actual state documentation or a case that sets precedent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not legal advice.

In general, [Florida v. Royer](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-supreme-court/460/491.html) says that only if there is a reasonable reason for doing so, a person may not be detained. For example:

> The person approached, however, need not answer any question put to
>   him; indeed, he may decline to listen to the questions at all and may
>   go on his way. He may not be detained even momentarily without
>   reasonable, objective grounds for doing so; and his refusal to listen
>   or answer does not, without more, furnish those grounds. If there is
>   no detention - no seizure within the meaning of the Fourth Amendment -
>   then no constitutional rights have been infringed.

The question came up how DUI checkpoints are related to this because here people (in vehicles) are briefly detained.

[Michigan Department of State Police v. Sitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_Department_of_State_Police_v._Sitz) (See also [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/496/444)) says that

- "Petitioner's highway sobriety checkpoint program is consistent with the Fourth Amendment." That is DUI check-points are legal. You are technically being detained for a short period of time. But, as you point out in your comment below, you don't have to submit to any test. The police at the stop will access you from the outside.

[Delaware v. Prouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaware_v._Prouse) (see also [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/440/648)) was cited in Michigan Dep't of State Police v. Sitz and says that

> Except where there is at least articulable and reasonable suspicion
>   that a motorist is unlicensed or that an automobile is not registered,
>   or that either the vehicle or an occupant is otherwise subject to
>   seizure for violation of law, stopping an automobile and detaining the
>   driver in order to check his driver's license and the registration of
>   the automobile are unreasonable under the Fourth Amendment.

Also, I find the following in Michigan Department of State Police v. Sitz referring to the Delaware v. Prouse  it is stated that the Supreme Court

> ...went on to state that our holding did not cast doubt on the
>   permissibility of roadside truck weigh-stations and inspection
>   checkpoints, at which some vehicles may be subject to further
>   detention for safety and regulatory inspection than are others.

So, if there might be some "inspection points" where you can be subjected to "further detention".

Comment: But field sobriety tests and preliminary breath tests (which are not admissible in court) are voluntary. So to which test do you suggest you are required to perform?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: You are right, let me update a bit.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.